# Semantic action in parser combinators

Tags: semantics, parser-combinator

I have a parser that can be defined as

`int = a:/[0-9]+/ {parseInt(a)}`.

It is supposed to match an int and convert it into a number. There can also be a parser like

`sum = a:int b:int {a+b}`

As you can see, it is a series of tokens, which means that they must be parsed as an array of tokens. When we start such an array, I allocate a scope for the variables. The trouble however is that the chain includes the semantic action. Parsing `1 2` with `int int` would produce `[1,2]` and semantic action `a+b`, which is also a parser, replaces that with `[3]`, three in the array, because sum is a chain of parsers and its result must be an array. But, normal user wants pure result `3`. How do I solve the problem?

Comment: normally parsing gives you a syntax tree, you would normally then walk over the tree to evaluate it

Comment: @jk 1+1=2. Keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Since the sequence is generated only for more than one parser in series and only javascript in the semantic action collapses it into singleton, singletone array can be safely converted into a value, extracting the single value from it.